# undefined method each rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was trying out ruby on rails through the tutorial located at http://ruby.railstutorial.org.
I got to to the point where I could create users and have their name and gravatar displayed at:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/1
```

Now I want to display all users when a user goes to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = User.all
  end      

  #...
end
```

Here is my view.

```
#View for index action in user's controleer

<h1>All users</h1>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I get the following error.

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Can someone tell me why the index page is not working as I want it to.

Comment: rename your variable `@user` to `@users` in your index action of your controller ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Is right, @user is unset and instance variables take the default value of `nil` when you try and access them, so `@users` is `nil` but `@user` is set.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem comes from the `@users` variable that does not exists:

In your index action you set `@user` to all users:

```
def index
  @user = User.all
end
```

By convention, we use pluralized names when we retrieve several entries from the DB, that's why you are calling `@users` (notice the 's') in the view. Just rename your `@user` to `@users` and it will be okay ;)

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

Comment: Ok - It may work but can you explain the reason - I mean it's a variable . right ? and i didn't know a language that imposes restriction on variable name strictly - so why in Rails

Comment: @ImranNaqvi Rails is not restricting you to use a specific pluralized name, but it is a convention to name your variables accordingly : `@users` is the best variable's name to describe a list of several `User` records.

Comment: Ok that's my question i.e if rails is not restricting me and that is only a convention then why it gives the error -undefined method each

Comment: because you did not use the exact same variable's name in the view. If you define `@whatever = User.all` in your controller's action, you will have to use the variable `@whatever` in the view.